# Not able to sort object array in vuex action Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, sorting, vue.js, vuex

I am trying sort an array, but somehow sort is not running only proved by console log. I am not able to understand why this is not running. if i run same code in simple javascript runs fine. It would be a great help if someone knows whats happening.

```
fetchContacts({
    commit
}, userId) {
    let contactsArr = [];
    console.log('contact action triggered');
    db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("contacts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((el) => {
            contactsArr.push({
                name: el.data().name,
                phone: el.data().phone,
                email: el.data().email,
                id: el.id
            });
        })
    })
    console.log('contact array: '+ contactsArr);
    console.log(contactsArr);
    contactsArr.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log('sorting in ');
        const n1 = a.name.toLowerCase();
        console.log(n1);
        const n2 = b.name.toLowerCase();
        console.log(n2);
        if (n1 > n2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n2 > n1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    commit('setContacts', contactsArr);
},
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The array is empty, so the sort function will not execute at all.

Comment: Hi Moon, array is not empty. Please check the console image i uploaded just now.

Comment: Your array actually was empty at the time when you sorted it. Chrome evaluates the array lazily when you expand it in the output, and by that time it has been populated by the prior async code.

Comment: this is did not know, this info would help in future also while debugging. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should un the sort inside the `onSnapshot` callback since your current code is executed in asynchronous way :

```
 let contactsArr = [];
    console.log('contact action triggered');
    db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("contacts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((el) => {
            contactsArr.push({
                name: el.data().name,
                phone: el.data().phone,
                email: el.data().email,
                id: el.id
            });
        })

      console.log('contact array: '+ contactsArr);
    console.log(contactsArr);
    contactsArr.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log('sorting in ');
        const n1 = a.name.toLowerCase();
        console.log(n1);
        const n2 = b.name.toLowerCase();
        console.log(n2);
        if (n1 > n2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n2 > n1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    commit('setContacts', contactsArr);
    })
```

Comment: I get that but my question is that if i am able to print the array before i do sorting than how I am not bale to sort it.  Thanks for replying.